# How to switch from integrated to dedicated gpu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm new to linux and I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I need to switch from integrated to dedicated gpu, or be able to launch some programs (ex. steam) with nvidia gpu. I had this problem previously and I solved it using:
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink ...
It worked until recently (I think until nvidia issued a new 510 driver). Now I can't use the above method to resolve my problem, because the output of
`xrandr --listproviders`
is:
*"Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting"*
so I can't switch between them.
I tried to:

1. purge the nvidia drivers and install the new one as in this (https://gist.github.com/espoirMur/65cec3d67e0a96e270860c9c276ab9fa) tutorial,
2. used "`sudo prime-select nvidia`",
3. changed profile to high performance in nvidia X server settings,
4. "`DRI-PRIME = 1`" command.

While trying to resolve the problem encountered that command:

```
$ nvidia-smi
*"NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."*
Search on this problem gave the tutorial which was similar to point 1 of the above steps (it didn't work as well, the output is the same).
```

Additional info:

```
$ lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
*00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)*

$ dkms status
*nvidia, 510.54, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed*

$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:151 memory:b5000000-b5ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0obh.png) of the system information.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. That info needs to be typed into or pasted into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Disabling secure boot in BIOS did it for me.
For those who don't know how to that:

1. Restart your computer.
2. Before loading OS pres rapidly f2 (on some computers it can be different).
3. In Bios menu on Boot page find "Secure boot" and made it disabled.
4. Exit with saving changes.

Also there is a possibility that the "Secure boot" option is not available to the changes. In this case on "Security page" set up the boot password and restart again and use the above instructions.

The content of boot menus on different PCs could be different, so some of the instructions may be a little different.