# Switch graphics AMD integrated to AMD dedicated

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, radeon

I am new on Linux and I tell you that I have a laptop model [ASUS TUF FX505DY-BQ024T](https://www.asus.com/us/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-gaming-fx505dy/techspec/) that has a hybrid graphics, an integrated graphics AMD Radeon RX Vega 8 and a dedicated graphics AMD Radeon RX 560X. To take advantage of the resources, I want to leave the dedicated graphics as primary, I have tried different options and configurations, but have not been successful.

Edit:

- I use Ubuntu 22.04.2
- My EFI BIOS does not have the option to change the graphics card.
- I have installed different drivers.
- I updated the Linux kernel version.
- I tried to follow the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ckiKQotNw
  But when I run the command `xrandr --listproviders`, I get 0 providers.
- I have a snapshot of Timeshift from before installing any additional drivers.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The basic option to switch the graphics card is in the BIOS. Try the EFI BIOS Setup first.

### Edit

You are correct, it looks like the ASUS BIOS does not include an option to set a graphics card preference. It's very unusual, but it's true.

What type and version of driver for the NVIDIA card do you have installed? Do you have the proprietary NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from the Ubuntu repository? What do you manage to set using the `nvidia-settings` package (NVIDIA X Server Settings)?

My other suggestion is: Try using the settings according to page:
[How to switch from integrated to dedicated gpu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394583/how-to-switch-from-integrated-to-dedicated-gpu)

If you want to update the BIOS to version 315, download it from the link:
https://www.asus.com/uk/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-gaming-fx505dy/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DY

I don't guarantee it will include graphics settings, but it will occasionally solve some other problems.

Comment: My laptop does not have the option to change the graphics card in the EFI BIOS.

I added additional information.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't have any Nvidia driver, because my computer is AMD. Effectively I have the BIOS version 315 installed.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault. I forgot what you said about the type of graphics card.